# Vectorizing R expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector, expression, annotate

I am trying to vectorize the title and subtitle of a figure within the R expression using atop() function as in the example below with no success. Could anyone help me with this?

```
title = "Text line 1"
subtitle = "Text line 2"

fig1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+geom_boxplot(stat = "boxplot")
fig2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+geom_point()
fg = ggarrange(fig1, fig2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

title <- expression(atop(title, scriptstyle(subtitle)))
annotate_figure(fg, top = text_grob(title, face = "bold", size = 14))
```

Comment: FYI, that isn’t what “vectorise” means ([here’s an explanation for vectorisation](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html)). I *think* you’re referring to “interpolation”.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `expression` use `bquote`. It allows for variable's evaluation.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

title = "Text line 1"
subtitle = "Text line 2"

fig1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg))+
  geom_boxplot(stat = "boxplot")
fig2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
  geom_point()
fg = ggarrange(fig1, fig2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

maintitle <- bquote(atop(.(title), scriptstyle(.(subtitle))), 
                    list(title = title, subtitle = subtitle))
annotate_figure(fg, top = text_grob(maintitle, face = "bold", size = 14))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: why is the dot before .(title) and .(subtitle). Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae The dot is to have `bquote` evaluate the variables.

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `expr` with `atop` and assign `!!` before the variables like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
title = "Text line 1"
subtitle = "Text line 2"

fig1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+geom_boxplot(stat = "boxplot")
fig2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+geom_point()
fg = ggarrange(fig1, fig2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

title <- expr(atop(!!title, scriptstyle(!!subtitle)))
annotate_figure(fg, top = text_grob(title, face = "bold", size = 14))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>